# Chart.js updating data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to add to my chart setTimeout function to updated data. Have code listed below but console is saying **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"** how to acces data array? and put my mew values? error is logging at the end of this code. in var ChartLine. Or maybe if you have any other idea how to update dynamically data please share your answer

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Data",
                borderColor: gradientStroke,
                pointBorderColor: gradientStroke,
                pointBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
                pointHoverBorderColor: gradientStroke,
                pointBorderWidth: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                pointRadius: 3,
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: gradientFill,
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: [50, 80, 130, 65, 100, 66, 86],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: "top"
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
                        fontStyle: "bold",
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        padding: 20
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        drawTicks: false,
                        display: false
                    }

                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        zeroLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 20,
                        fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
                        fontStyle: "bold"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

   setTimeout(function addData(chart, label, data) {
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push([45, 45, 45, 15, 3]);
        });
        chart.update();
    }, 2000);
```

thanks you for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be updating the chart data as follows :

```
setTimeout(function() {
   addData(myChart, [45, 50, 30, 34, 61, 53, 42], 0);
}, 2000);

function addData(chart, data, datasetIndex) {
   chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = data;
   chart.update();
}
```

**Working Example**

```js
var gradientStroke = 'rgba(0, 119, 220, 0.6)',
    gradientFill = 'rgba(0, 119, 220, 0.4)';

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
      datasets: [{
         label: "Data",
         borderColor: gradientStroke,
         pointBorderColor: gradientStroke,
         pointBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
         pointHoverBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
         pointHoverBorderColor: gradientStroke,
         pointBorderWidth: 5,
         pointHoverRadius: 5,
         pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
         pointRadius: 3,
         fill: true,
         backgroundColor: gradientFill,
         borderWidth: 2,
         data: [50, 80, 130, 65, 100, 66, 86],
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: {
         position: "top"
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
               fontStyle: "bold",
               beginAtZero: true,
               maxTicksLimit: 5,
               padding: 20
            },
            gridLines: {
               drawTicks: false,
               display: false
            }

         }],
         xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
               zeroLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
            },
            ticks: {
               padding: 20,
               fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
               fontStyle: "bold"
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});


setTimeout(function() {
   addData(myChart, [45, 50, 30, 34, 61, 53, 42], 0);
}, 2000);

function addData(chart, data, datasetIndex) {
   chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = data;
   chart.update();
}
```

```css
* { background: #111 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="350" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: how to exisitng data in array?not to add new data but simply change those already exisiting?

Comment: you wanna replace all the data with new one..?